# What's the proper way to set NODE_ENV in Karma for running webpack?

Tags: node.js, gulp, karma-runner, webpack

I'm building my project with Webpack and using Karma for running tests.

I want to configure Karma to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to "test" for Webpack to perform conditional build of the project for testing environment with URLs mapped to localhost, not production domain name.

For that purpose I make use of Webpack's `env-replace-loader`, which reads its configuration file `environments.json` and sets variables, such as API_URL, depending on the values of `process.env.NODE_ENV`. In production build I use Gulp to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` and start webpack. It works.

I want to set `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'` in testing build, initiated by running `karma start karma.conf.js`. Currently I just say `process.env.NODE_ENV = "test"` in `karma.conf.js`.

Is there a better way to do that?

---

Besides, I tried to use DefinePlugin of webpack in `webpack.config.js` to set this variable like this:

```
const webpackConfig = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            process.env: {'NODE_ENV': 'test'}
        }),
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

and it won't work: webpack `env-replace-loader` curses that `Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined` - I suppose, it can not access the node reports that it doesn't see

Comment: Try `'"test"'`. Note the "'s. It replaces literally so it will fail without. `JSON.stringify` would be another option.

Answer (score 11):

In your webpack config try this JSON.stringify('name') instead. Try something like this:

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
            APP_ENV: JSON.stringify('browser')
        },
    })
  ],
```

That works with the webpack running a example or something like that. For example, I'm using that to require CSS when running an example but it get ignored when compiling for production.

I got the same problem with Karma config but I fix that adding the plugin into the webpack part of the Karma config file. It's my file for example:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    files: [
      'tests.webpack.js',
      {
        pattern: 'src/**/__tests__/*.js',
        included: false,
        served: false,
        watched: true
      }
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    preprocessors: {
      'tests.webpack.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap', 'coverage'],
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'notification'],
    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('test')
            }
        })
      ],
      watch: true
    },
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true,
    }
  });
};
```

I hope that's helpfull for you too!